# finding the nearest leap year to user's input in c

Tags: c, leap-year

my homework is in c.
program:check if user's input is not leap year then find the nearest leap year to user's input.
variable:y
1300<y<1400

I think the best way is to write it with while loop like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int year;
   scanf("%d", &year);
   while(1300<year<1400)
   {
     if (year % 100 == 0)
     {
        //i don't know:(
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A no-brainer approach would be to check if current year is a leap. If not, assign current year value to two variables and then loop for up to three years, incrementing one and decrementing the other. Terminate as soon as one of them becomes a leap.

Comment: You can't do two comparisons that way. `1300<year<1400` should be `1300<year && year<1400`.

Comment: Leap year is: divisible by 4 but not a leap year if divisible by 100 unless divisible by 400

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the task is invalid, since the Gregorian calendar [wasn't in use](https://www.thoughtco.com/gregorian-calendar-1434504) between 1300 and 1400 CE. But let's ignore that...

So, you need to remind yourself of a proper rule for determining if a year is a leap year or not:

> In the Gregorian calendar, three criteria must be taken into account
> to identify leap years:
>
> - The year must be evenly divisible by 4.
> - If the year can also be evenly divided by 100, it is not a leap year;
> - Unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap
>   year.

(Taken from [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html))

Now, I suggest you write a function which, given a year, returns `true` if it's a leap year and `false` otherwise. It's usually a good idea, once you've defined a piece of your computation with distinct inputs and outputs, to separate it out into a function, rather than write everything within a single large main program.

Finally, use the function in the loop in your main program. Note that, as @stark points out, you can't write the loop the way that you have, i.e. C doesn't support a  `lower_bound < variable < upper_bound` notation like we're used to from continued math equations; you have to separate that into two expressions with a logical "and": `(lower_bound < variable) && (variable < upper_bound)`.

Also, since you're just iterating through all year, you might want to consider a for loop:

```
for(int year = 1301; year < 1400; year++) {
    // do things with year 
}
```

Comment: Detail: True that Gregorian calendar was not used until the 1500s, yet today, referring to years before that may simple employ the [Proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar).  Early years best with annotation to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, fixed that.